# How can the Wcf Test Client be used without Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, wcf

When WcfTestClient.exe is copied to another machine by itself, runtime errors prevent you from connecting to a WCF service, for example:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or Assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

How can this tool be used without installing Visual Studio?

Comment: This is a valid question working professionals wind up needing the answer to over and over. Any suggestions on how to reduce the broad nature of the question instead of closing something with such value?

Answer (score 20):

To run `WCFTestClient.exe` as a standalone appplication *(without install a full version of Visual Studio 2010)*:

1. Create a directory in the `dest.` machine and copy `wcftestclient.exe` there *(only that file)*.
2. Copy Microsoft.VisualStudio.VirtualTreeGrid.dll (version 10)  from file below to same directory of `wcftestclient.exe` in the `dest.` machine.

   ```
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.VirtualTreeGrid\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a
   ```
3. You would create in your destination machine the following two registry keys:

   ```
   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x64]
   "InstallationFolder"="\"

   [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86]
   "InstallationFolder"="\"
   ```

   **Step note:** You could export them from your development machine *(maybe you could find another version, but please try with v7.0A first)*.
4. Then you will need copy from:

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\svcutil.exe
   ```

   to your destination machine *(same directory as `wcftestclient.exe`)*

   **Step note:** Is important this version of `svcutil.exe`
5. Run `wcftestclient.exe`

**Final notes:** You will need only two `.exe` files and one `.dll` *(`wcftestclient.exe, svcutil.exe and Microsoft.VisualStudio.VirtualTreeGrid.dll`)* to run the application.

<sup>[More information](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c3c7221c-c06f-4364-887a-fb20f22877be/wcf-test-client-problem)</sup>

Comment: The zip from the download link doesn't need a registry edit and contains the following files: WcfSvcHost.exe.config, Microsoft.VisualStudio.VirtualTreeGrid.dll, _System.Data.dll_, WcfTestClient.chm, SvcUtil.exe, WcfTestClient.exe.config, WcfSvcHost.exe, SvcUtil.exe.config, WcfTestClient.exe, WcfSvcHost.chm

Comment: I followed the instructions and it worked without the registry edit.

Answer (score 15):

The above mentioned link doesn't work anymore.
New page that contains a link: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/workandstudybook/archive/2014/06/03/standalone-wcftestclient.aspx

Comment: @Benj: this should have been a comment.

Answer (score 8):

The direct link of file Benj pointed, is https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4CF16D17C29C8F61!1580&authkey=!ADkPUmhfdAQS5Hg&ithint=file%2c.zip

Comment: This may serve better as a comment or even edit to Benj's answer, rather than a standalone one. It doesn't really provide additional value to the existing answers to this question.

Comment: By the way, .NET 3.5 is required to run the full WcfTestClient.exe.