# Where can I find WcfTestClient.exe (part of Visual Studio)

Tags: wcf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

The [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) state that I can find the *WCF Test Client* in:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\

but it seems like a lot of stuff is missing from there, including *WcfTestClient.exe*.

What do I need to install?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio (Your Version Here)\Common7\IDE

Comment: Should it be of any help to future readers, after installing VS2012 on an x64 machine this program was located here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe

Comment: for x64 systems it's under the (x86) path, for non 64-bit it's under program files

Comment: Please check Gaspa79's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37530146/352640) for the most recent versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: Please note that, as of VS 2017, this answer is not valid anymore. See below the answer by Gaspa79 for the right path (tl;dr: access the folder called simply "Microsoft Visual Studio" WITHOUT the version number, in ProgFiles, and open the same subfolder)

Answer (score 134):

VS 2022 Professional:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe
```

VS 2022 Community:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe
```

VS 2022 Enterprise:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe
```

VS 2019 Professional:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe
```

VS 2019 Community:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe
```

VS 2019 Enterprise:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe
```

VS 2017 Community:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe
```

VS 2017 Professional:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe
```

VS 2017 Enterprise:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe
```

VS 2015:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe
```

VS 2013:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe
```

VS 2012:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe
```

Comment: Does 2019 Professional not have it?

Comment: I have 2019 Professional installed and 'WcfTestClient.exe' is not in the specified folder.

Comment: @peteym do you know its location? I can update the post =)

Comment: @Gaspa79 the location you listed is correct, I was missing the exe.  kroe761 post below pointed me in the right direction, needed to install Windows Communication Foundation.

Answer (score 87):

The prerequisite to have WcfTestClient is to have Windows Communication Foundation component installed. If WcfTestClient is missing, install it by modifying Visual Studio:

Control Panel > Apps & Features > Visual Studio (*your version*)

In Visual Studio Installer, click on Modify, choose *Individual components* tab and then select (see below screenshot):

> ☑ Windows Communication Foundation

Click on Modify and *voilà*, application will be on your disk.

[image: Visual Studio Installer]

If you want to use WcfTestClient with no Visual Studio, see answer(s) on: [How can the Wcf Test Client be used without Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340082/how-can-the-wcf-test-client-be-used-without-visual-studio)

Answer (score 40):

In addition, one can add this to the Visual Studio Tools menu.

Tools => External Tools.

And then in the Command box enter the path for WcfTestClient.exe.

In my case

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe

[image]

Answer (score 39):

FYI - I could not find `WcfTestClient.exe` under any of the listed file paths.  It turns out it needed to be installed by Visual Studio Installer.  When you launch the installer and modify your version of VS, make sure `Windows Communication Foundation` is checked under Optional.  It may seem obvious, but it wasn't to me and therefore might not be obvious to everyone else.

Answer (score 24):

You won't find the component if it hasn't been installed.

In Visual Studio 2019 go to:

Tools >  Get Tools and Features > Select the Individual Components tab > Type `wcf` in the search box and install it.

This installs the component, and you should be able to load it from the command prompt or other methods suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 10):

If you use "Developer Command Prompt" you can just type `WcfTestClient` to start it or type `where wcftestclient` to find the location.

Comment: This answer is much more useful to new people and provides much more instructional information than just giving the typical location. It also accounts for cases where users don't have their Program Files* folders on the %SYSTEMDRIVE% (which is entirely possible)

Comment: Thanks.  The where command told me instantly that it was at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE

Answer (score 6):

For Visual studio 2013, Windows 8...

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe

Answer (score 4):

New Direction on VS 2017 (x64 systems)

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\*your lic type*\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe"
```

Answer (score 2):

Mine was here:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE"

Answer (score 0):

For 64 bit OS, its here (If .Net 4.5) : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE