# Where is the WCF Test Client in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've recently upgraded to visual studio 2015.   I don't see the WCF Test Client listed under the Tools menu like in previous versions.   Is it still avaliable in VS 2015 and if so where?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find WcfTestClient.exe (part of Visual Studio)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915733/where-can-i-find-wcftestclient-exe-part-of-visual-studio)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The executable is usually located here:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe

[image]

Other useful utilities can be found there as well.

You can pin it to start menu or taskbar if you use it often.

HTH