# Visual Studio 2017 WcfTestClient.exe not existing

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2017, wcftestclient

The problem is simple, this thing is just not installed.
And can't find any installer on the web.

"where wcftestclient" returns a not found.

When i press F5 and WCF project is selected, it just open my browser and show my svc. Useless.

What's wrong with my VS installation? Should i instal some SDK or so..?

[image]

Comment: Absolute duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9915733/where-can-i-find-wcftestclient-exe-part-of-visual-studio. You can find answer here.

Comment: @Hameed have you seen my screenshot? Have seen this question, I'm in the right folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE" as said but nothing there..

Comment: HAve you tried this,Goto start->All Programs->Microsoft Visual Studio 2017->Visual Studio Tools.Open Developer Command Prompt for VS2017.Then type wcftestclient.exe and hit enter

Comment: Yeah that doesn't work, and when i type "where wcftestclient" it can't find it.  On another pc it's working well "C:\Users\Grounch\source>where wcftestclient.exe"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe"

Comment: last thing is you can check is event viewer.

Comment: Event viewer? Is wcftestclient installed automatically with VS Studio? Maybe i can try a reinstal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wanted to reinstal. Checked Windows Communication Foundation in visual studio installer components. Solved... sorry for not smart problem