# WCF test client utility generates error after method calling

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm executing a WCF Service and it starts well.

When I try to test the service from WCF Test Client the methods list is showed correctly.
[image: WCF Interface]

But when I try to executive a method this error message appears.

[image: Error message]

I tried to repair Visual Studio, uninstall and reinstall it, delete the ComponentModelCache, but it didn't work. How can I do?

Comment: Looks like app may need a different version of the library.  Use Solution explorer and delete the existing reference to library.  Than add the library which will update the version.

Comment: I also tried to remove the library reference but the error remains.

Also uninstall and reinstall the library has done nothing,  unfortunately.

Comment: Do a clean build.  One of the obj intermediate files still contains the reference.

Comment: It hasn't worked

Comment: VirtualTreeGrid is a 32 bit dll (not 64).  If you are targeting "Any CPU" you are probably defaulting to 64 bit mode.  So make sure you are using 32 bit if the library is installed on your machine.  The dll is old and is not part of latest Net library release.   It probably worked when using older versions of Net before Net 4.5 which used multiple versions of Net (1.0.2.0,3.0,3.5,4.0,4.1,4.2,4.3,4.4).  Since now there is one version of Net installed the older obsolete libraries have been removed.

Comment: I've tried to target it on the x86 mode, but that way the application won't even start, generation a System.BadImageFormatException

Comment: Did you do a clean build?

Comment: You can try running WCFTestClient.exe as a standalone application (no need to install full version of VS).https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340082/how-can-the-wcf-test-client-be-used-without-visual-studio and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/wcf-test-client-wcftestclient-exe#outside-visual-studio